# Shielding effectiveness calculation

Tags: emc, shielding

From [The Basic Principles of Shielding](http://www.incompliancemag.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=334:the-basic-principles-of-shielding&catid=24:current-issue&Itemid=126):

> Apertures, or holes, have SE. The SE of an aperture and ultimately the
> entire electronic enclosure is determined by the size, shape and
> number of the apertures. The formula is:
>
> [image: 1006_F1_eq1]
>
> Where: λ = Wavelength k = 20 for a slit or 40 for a round hole L =
> Longest dimension of the aperture If there is more than one hole, we
> subtract from the original formula: the total number of holes within
> half a wavelength.

Likewise, [Analyse on shielding effectiveness of board level shielding with apertures](http://www.digikey.com/Web%20Export/Supplier%20Content/laird-emi-903/pdf/laird-emi-analyse-on-shielding.pdf?redirected=1) says:

> $$\mathrm{SE\ (dB)} = K \log_{10} \left (\frac{λ}{2 L} \right ) - 20 \log_{10}(n)$$
>
> Where: n = numbers of apertures within a half wavelength

and [Rule-of-Thumb for Calculating Aperture Size](http://www.lairdtech.com/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=3400) says "n=number of apertures within λ/2"

But what does this mean?  Number of holes in a circle with half-wavelength radius?  (When I try to calculate this way, the first part of the expression is 275 dB, while the second half is 277 dB, producing a *negative* SE.)  Number of holes along a line half a wavelength long?

Can you work through an example calculation for, say, a microwave oven door with triangularly-packed holes?

Comment: I have seen similar equation in a [book by Henry Ott](http://www.amazon.com/Electromagnetic-Compatibility-Engineering-Henry-Ott/dp/0470189304). The book says that this equation is applicable to a linear array of closely spaced apertures. But this same expression is used for calculating SE of two dimensional array of apertures also. In that case \$n\$ is the maximum number of holes lined up in a straight line, horizontal, vertical, or diagonal.

Comment: @nidhin He also uses 10 log10(n) instead of 20 log10(n).  hmmm

Comment: yes. He says that "For a linear array of closely spaced apertures, the reduction in shielding effectiveness is proportional to the square root of the number of apertures (n)". Hence 10log instead of 20log.